# How can I write a firebase rule for my database so that it prevents certain users from being able to write?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

My firebase rules currently are set as:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

However, I'd like to create 1 testing account such that I can give it to potential testers and developers, but where no writing is permitted after I create the account. If I have the account number as `/users/{userId}`, how can I implement it into the code above but still have any queries of mine be valid? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to assign this specific access right to one specific userId (you wrote "I have the account number").

The following, directly using this specific userId, should work (untested):

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid != "THEUSERIDFORTHETESTER";
    }
  }
}
```

---

- All authenticated users can read
- All authenticated users, but the testing user, can write